# Poll in two languages

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, polls

I've installed Poll Core module in Drupal 7 trying to display the same poll with the same result in two languages (English and Arabic) but Drupal treats each one as a separate poll with different result ...

How could I do this?

Is there any other module can handle this?

I've tried Advanced Poll but I cannot use it I do not know how?

Comment: @clive : is this question re-opened because this applies to D7 and the other D6? or is there any other reason?

Comment: @indrock Yep, it's _technically_ a different question because of the differing version so I thought I was a bit hasty closing it. Much fairer to give it a chance I think :)

Comment: @Clive I too was among the one's flagging the question to be closed(no offense - in.studio), but its fair enough to be kept active. I second your thoughts :)

Comment: Thank you guys and never mind Clive, I think it deserve a chance :) best

Comment: Also, in the other question the OP is saying that he installed two third-party modules, while this question doesn't mention those modules. Clearly, if there is an answer for the other question, then the same answer is valid for this question; the only difference is that an answer for this question would first say "Install this, and that module."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem as follows:

1. Download the i18n patch from [here](http://drupal.org/files/1173130_i18n_poll_module_5.patch)
2. Apply the patch using any preferred technique, you can refer to [Drupal](http://drupal.org/patch/apply)
3. Applying should be on a test drupal installation in order to avoid any problems
4. After that go to modules page and enable the Poll Aggregate module under i18n, this will synch the voting results for all installed languages
5. After testing the patched module and getting happy result, install the module on your live site.

I have test this solution and it is OK with some small problems that I am trying to solve, and I will share the new things.