# Poll with multilingual choices in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I've installed the poll module in Drupal 7 and I want to have a multilingual poll, so that the choices could be in differents languages and sum the votes of the choices. I've found these posts:

[Multi language Poll output](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66280/multi-language-poll-output)

[Poll in two languages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51513/poll-in-two-languages)

The problem is that I'm not able to develop the solution because I don't know where I have to apply the patch since i18n module in drupal 7 doesn't include the i18n_poll subfolder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

@chabea you are right in asking the question, the answers given in the links above do not explain how to apply the patch on D7. Here is what you need to do:

1. Under the `i18n` module created a `i18n_poll` folder.
2. Copy [the patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/1173130_i18n_poll_module_5.patch) to the above folder.
3. Run the command `patch < 1173130_i18n_poll_module_5.patch`. This creats two files `i18n_poll.info` and `i18n_poll.module` which are all you need to get the `poll aggregate` module in D7. **(I'm assuming you are using *nix operating system and have already enabled the core poll module)** You can checkout [how to apply a patch in Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply).
4. Then go to the poll content type edit page `Structure > Content Types > Poll > Edit`. In the `publishing options - multilingual support` section check the `Enable, with translation` option.
   [image]
5. Now go to the poll content type create page `Content > Add Content > Poll` and create a new poll.
6. On the newly create poll page there is a `Translate` link.
   [image]
7. The translation page provides a list of language that the poll can be translated to so click on the language of your choice to start translation.
   [image]

The translation workflow is quite consistent to other modules/content types. Hope this helps.